# How to login to your repo and work from it using git

Tags: git, github

i already have an existing repo on github but i want to use my command line to hook on to it again and work on it after i shut down my computer but it is not working. should i clone it or something? i still have the project locally on my machine

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking but I think git remote would be the command you want. Specifically git remote add.  Look at [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) for more detail.

Comment: i want to clone it so that any when i do something like git commit, i can see the commit on my github page

Comment: It doesn't work that way @nana.  You do a commit locally and then you need to push your changes to your remote repo.

Comment: i just want to see the changes i make to my local project, taking effect on the one on github. i do a commit and push buh  nothing happens

Comment: You need to add more details to your question.  Exactly which steps are you taking?  You need to be explicit about the exact steps you're taking and in which order.

Comment: i was watching a tutorial and the guy copied ths SSH and did something like `git clone git@github.com:nanadjei2/hofsa.git` but i keep getting this error `git clone git@github.com:nanadjei2/hofsa.git
Cloning into 'hofsa'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` when i do the same thing

Comment: I'm looking at that repo--there's a change posted there 6 hours ago.  https://github.com/nanadjei2/hofsa/commit/0b6ca12f305ad71c8dbfd4d409a8fde9e52b381f  Just about the time you asked your question.  Are you sure your change didn't get posted?

Comment: i just checked it did buh i dont know how... i dont really know how long it takes to sync because i waited a bit longer and nothing was happening.

Comment: I think you'd be well-served to look at this site: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/